# Flatten array and reformat the JSON using jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to accomplish two things:

- Flatten the array in this json
- Reformat the json to a simple payload

Here's is the json I'm working with:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "feed": "jqQuestion",
  "organization": "question.com",
  "category": "question",
  "contact": {
    "name": "",
    "email": "",
    "phone": ""
  },
  "website": "https://thankyou.com/",
  "schedule": "daily",
  "stamp_added": "2017-09-27 00:00:00",
  "stamp_updated": "2022-09-10 15:51:09",
  "stamp_pulled": "2022-09-10 08:51:03",
  "stamp_modified": "2019-08-07 18:29:00",
  "nextarray": {
    "value": 1,
    "value2": 2
  }
}
```

I'm hoping to remove the "title" of the arrays, just keep the content, and align the contents of the array with the reset of the json:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "feed": "jqQuestion",
  "organization": "question.com",
  "category": "question",
  "name": "",
  "email": "",
  "phone": ""
  "website": "https://thankyou.com/",
  "schedule": "daily",
  "stamp_added": "2017-09-27 00:00:00",
  "stamp_updated": "2022-09-10 15:51:09",
  "stamp_pulled": "2022-09-10 08:51:03",
  "stamp_modified": "2019-08-07 18:29:00",
  "value": 1,
  "value2": 2
}
```

I've tried a few approaches, using sed, awk, and jq. I think using jq would be "optimal", but haven't been able to get the format right with the mentioned approaches. Any guidance here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `contact` and `nextarray` are the sub-objects to merge, then:

```bash
jq '. + .contact + .nextarray | del(.contact) | del(.nextarray)' file.json
```

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "feed": "jqQuestion",
  "organization": "question.com",
  "category": "question",
  "website": "https://thankyou.com/",
  "schedule": "daily",
  "stamp_added": "2017-09-27 00:00:00",
  "stamp_updated": "2022-09-10 15:51:09",
  "stamp_pulled": "2022-09-10 08:51:03",
  "stamp_modified": "2019-08-07 18:29:00",
  "name": "",
  "email": "",
  "phone": "",
  "value": 1,
  "value2": 2
}
```

The `+` operator, when given object operands, will merge the objects.

Generically:

```bash
jq '
    to_entries 
    | map(if (.value|type) == "object" then .value else {(.key): .value} end) 
    | add
'
```

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "feed": "jqQuestion",
  "organization": "question.com",
  "category": "question",
  "name": "",
  "email": "",
  "phone": "",
  "website": "https://thankyou.com/",
  "schedule": "daily",
  "stamp_added": "2017-09-27 00:00:00",
  "stamp_updated": "2022-09-10 15:51:09",
  "stamp_pulled": "2022-09-10 08:51:03",
  "stamp_modified": "2019-08-07 18:29:00",
  "value": 1,
  "value2": 2
}
```

Comment: With fields known, you could replace the `.` with a unified `del` to eliminiate the pipes: `del(.contact, .nextarray) + .contact + .nextarray`. And in the generic version, you could also use `with_entries` to get rid of `add`: `with_entries(if .value|type == "object" then .value|to_entries[] else . end)`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> jq -c 'to_entries[]|flatten[]'
> ```

would already get you to

```
"id"
1
"feed"
"jqQuestion"
"organization"
"question.com"
"category"
"question"
"contact"
{"name":"","email":"","phone":""}
"website"
"https://thankyou.com/"
"schedule"
"daily"
"stamp_added"
"2017-09-27 00:00:00"
"stamp_updated"
"2022-09-10 15:51:09"
"stamp_pulled"
"2022-09-10 08:51:03"
"stamp_modified"
"2019-08-07 18:29:00"
"nextarray"
{"value":1,"value2":2}
```

to create ur desired output should be trivial from here